# How to call a getter from another class, when the object is not given?

Tags: java, class, static, undefined, getter

For the code below I have a constructor Puzzle with a corresponding getter.

```
public class Puzzle {

private int [][] array;

    public Puzzle(int[][] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    public int[][] getArray() {
        return this.array;
    }

}
```

In another class I want to have a non static method that solves the puzzle. But I need to use the getter to get the 2D array...

```
public class Solver {

    public void solve() {
        int[][] a1 = getArray();
    }
    //...More Code here ...
}
```

I want it to be solved so that in a main method it can be called as such ...

```
puzzle.solve();
```

However the getArray() method is said to be undefined in the class Solver. Is there any way around this without having to accept the puzzle to be solved using solve(puzzle)?

Comment: You have to create objects, for use the method of a class.

Comment: Give the puzzle to the solver. Or the solver to the puzzle. But you can't call instance methods of a class unless you have an instance, and call them on that instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to create an instance of the class:

```
public class Solver {

    public void solve() {
        int[][] a2 = { {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3} };
        Puzzle puzzle = new Puzzle(a2);
        int[][] a1 = puzzle.getArray();
    }
    //...More Code here ...
}
```

The following code answers your question, but it doesn't make much sense. You've to ask yourself, an array from which object I want to get? Do you have such object in your code? Than you have to pass this object to solve method and call `getArray()` on that object.

```
public class Solver {

    public void solve(Puzzle puzzle) {
        int[][] a1 = puzzle.getArray();
    }
    //...More Code here ...
}
```